# Format a number in Google Appscript with setNumberFormat

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having trouble with some Google Appscript code. I'm still learning the basic coding stuff so I apologize if this is too simple of a question. Code is not mine, I borrowed from GitHub (can't recall exactly whom from). It's functioning it's quite explained in the code comments, but it basically takes all rows in a spreadsheet and replaces values on a template Document, which is then saved individually in a folder.

What I need to do, is to format the number in column 17 (row[17] in the code) adding zeros before the number, so that, for example, the number 1 gets printed as '00000001'. The number should always be 8 digits long. When running this code, I'm getting the error "row is not a function".

Here's the whole code:

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('Recibos');
  menu.addItem('Generar recibos', 'createNewGoogleDocs')
  menu.addToUi();

}

function createNewGoogleDocs() {
  //This value should be the id of your document template that we created in the last step
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1bWU-bVk-z4Rl1T7a-0ynveGRxLadgfFoHOMNhmnpccs');
  
  //This value should be the id of the folder where you want your completed documents stored
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1-NkH7otODyKe8rffTZepkzwEygud2ga0')
  //Here we store the sheet as a variable
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName('Facturación')
  
  //Now we get all of the values as a 2D array
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  //Start processing each spreadsheet row
  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    //Here we check if this row is the headers, if so we skip it
    if (index === 0) return;
    //Here we check if a document has already been generated by looking at 'Document Link', if so we skip it
    if (row[21]) return;
    //Using the row data in a template literal, we make a copy of our template document in our destinationFolder
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`Recibo ${row[6]}, - ${row[7]}, - ${row[9]}` , destinationFolder)
    //Once we have the copy, we then open it using the DocumentApp
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    //All of the content lives in the body, so we get that for editing
    const body = doc.getBody();
    //In this line we do some friendly date formatting, that may or may not work for you locale
    const friendlyDate = new Date(row[0]).toLocaleDateString();
    const nroReciboCeros = new Number(row(17).setNumberFormat('00000000'));
    
    //In these lines, we replace our replacement tokens with values from our spreadsheet row
    body.replaceText('{{Obra Social}}', row[6]);
    body.replaceText('{{CUIT OS}}', row[5]);
    body.replaceText('{{monto en letras}}', row[19]);
    body.replaceText('{{Concepto}}', row[20]);
    body.replaceText('{{N° FC}}', row[3]);
    body.replaceText('{{fechaFactura}}', friendlyDate);
    body.replaceText('{{medio de pago}}', row[14]);
    body.replaceText('{{monto en nro}}', row[10]);
    body.replaceText('{{N° rec}}', nroReciboCeros);
    
    //We make our changes permanent by saving and closing the document
    doc.saveAndClose();
    //Store the url of our new document in a variable
    const url = doc.getUrl();
    //Write that value back to the 'Document Link' column in the spreadsheet. 
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 22).setValue(url)
    
  })
  
}
```

What I tried to do, was using 'Number" as a constructor, but I guess I don't understand well how constructors work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you getting error because of you have a typo row().  to access items from array/list should use [] instead of ().  You can use pad function to make the desire length.   const nroReciboCeros = String(row[17]).padStart(8,0)

Comment: column 17 is row[16]

Comment: @liquidkat - I believe your comment is the actual answer for OP problem. Could you post your comment as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Nikko J.

You getting error because of you have a typo row(). To access items from array/list should use [] instead of (). You can use pad function to make the desire length.

```
const nroReciboCeros = String(row[17]).padStart(8,0)
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. But, every number gets printed as '00000000' (all zeros). could that be because of converting the numbers to a string?
If I try with setNumberFormat function with [], error still appears, as if setNumberFormat doesn't exist.

Comment: String(row[17]).padStart(8,0) what this code do is , turn what's inside row[17] into string then pad the 0 from beginning of row[17] to make a 8 digit number (string).  If your row[17] is 0, then it will be '00000000'.   setNumberFormat function applies to range not value. Try sheet.getRange('C1').setNumberFormat('00000000') you will find out.   enter a number at C1 then run a test

Comment: when you in the rows.forEach funtion , row is the each row value.   [ [row1], [row2]], inside row[1] that's your data [1,2,3,4,5].   If you want to use your setNumberFormat('00000000') inside forEach function.  Then you have to get the range first.    const range = sheet.getRange(index+1,18).setNumberFormat('00000000').  index +1 is the row in your sheet, and 18 is row[17 +1] the column index.     ! it's NOT a good practice to call sheet.getrange in a loop. it would make your code slow!